# javascript createelement for dynamic drop down menu

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm new to `createElement` property in JavaScript. I need to create a dropdown menu from the MySQL query. I have created a PHP array from the MySQL query, which is given below:

```
<?
$vendorInformation=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `vendor`",$con);
$row=array();

while($v=mysql_fetch_assoc($vendorInformation))
{
    $row[]= $v['id'];
    $row[]= $v['name'];
}

$row=json_encode($row);
echo $row;
//OUTPUT: ["1","Cisco","2","Juniper","3","Opengear"] 
?>
```

Then I wrote the JavaScript code:

```
<script>
var inputs = 1;
var v_array = <?=$row;?>;
//OUTPUT for v_array: 1,Cisco,2,Juniper,3,Opengear
var inp3 = document.createElement('SELECT');
var o=document.createElement("option");
inp3.setAttribute("id","v"+(inputs));

for (var i = 0; i < v_array.length; i++)
{
    var o=document.createElement("option");
    o.setAttribute("name","red");
    o.setAttribute("value","me");
    o.innerHTML=name;
    inp3.appendChild(o);
}
</script>
```

I'm not sure how can I complete this code.

**As per the array's output, the option value should be 1,2,3 and values should be Cisco,Juniper,Opengear(respectively).**

Comment: I'm not sure where name and value come from, but you have to give o the attributes from v_array, and at the end do inp3.appendChild(o). And then append inp3 to the document element you want.

Comment: yes, that was my confusion. I think I need to iterate through the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off using this format in your PHP:

```
while($v = mysql_fetch_assoc($vendorInformation)) {
    $row[] = array(
        "id"=>$v['id'],
        "name"=>$v['name']
    );
}
```

Then, in your JavaScript, you can do this:

```
var inp3 = document.createElement('select'),
    l = v_array.length, i;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    inp3.options[i] = new Option(v_array[i].name,v_array[i].id);
}
```